# looping on elements loaded by .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I'm using .load() method to get some data on ('document').load() event, but i'm not able to loop over elements within loaded content.

here's my code:

```
$('document').ready(function() { 
    $('#questions').load('survey/questions');
    $('.questions').each(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('id'))
    })
});
```

thanks!

Comment: You're mixing `#questions` and `.questions` -- was that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the contents only once the AJAX call completes (remember that AJAX is asynchronous meaning that when you call the [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) the method simply sends a request to the server but the response could come much later). That's why this function provides a callback which will be invoked once the AJAX call completes and where you could manipulate the result from the server:

```
$('document').ready(function() { 
      $('#questions').load('survey/questions', function() {
          // Remark: your original selector was #questions whereas here
          // you have .questions which is not the same selector
          $('.questions').each(function() {
              alert($(this).attr('id'));
          });
      });
   });
});
```